# How to implement a spinning line in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I'm trying to implement a line that rotates at a given coordinate on the map. The line is not a polyline and it should be the same length irrespective of the zoom level. I've googled for a few days and I've found out how to spin things using CSS and how to draw a proper line using Leaflet's DivIcon. I thought everything was ready, but, when I put them together, my DivIcon is not placed where I put it. Please, check my code below and the result(https://jsfiddle.net/yckim1224/380de3gb/1/). I placed myIcon1, and myIcon2 at the same coordinate and make only myIcon2 to spin. The result is that myIcon2 is spinning at the top left corner while myIcon1 keep its location. myIcon2 is even moving when I zoom out.

This is my first web project, so, I'm not familiar with Web things like CSS and Javascript. So, please, 1. review my code and teach me what is wrong, and, 2. if there is any better way to draw a spinning line, give me some advice.

my CSS code:

```
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.my-div-icon-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.my-div-icon-2 {
  background-color: green;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 1000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

my Javascript code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [36.8, 127.5],
        zoom: 10
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var myIcon1 = L.divIcon({ 
    iconSize: new L.Point(2, 50),
    iconAnchor: [0, 0],
    className: 'my-div-icon-1'    
});
L.marker([37.0, 127.5], {icon: myIcon1}).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('myIcon1');

var myIcon2 = L.divIcon({ 
    iconSize: new L.Point(2, 50),
    iconAnchor: [0, 0],
    className: 'my-div-icon-2'    
});    
L.marker([37.0, 127.5], {icon: myIcon2}).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup('myIcon2');
```